# Java Generic Type - could not use generic type as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, class, generics, types

```
public class pencil<T> {
 private T []a;

 public pencil(T[] a) {
    this.a=(T[]) a;
 }
 public void pencil1() {
    for (int i = 0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if (a[i]== "pen") {
            System.out.println("pen");
            
        }
 }
}
 public class objQueue<T>  {
       private T[] queue;
       private int frontIndex;
       private int backIndex;

    
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       public objQueue() {
         T[] Queue1=(T[]) new Object[10];
         queue=Queue1;
         frontIndex=-1;
         backIndex=-1;
}


    
       public void enqueue(T newEntry) {
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is full");
    }
        else {
        
           if(frontIndex== -1) {
        
              frontIndex=0;
        }
        backIndex =(backIndex+1)% queue.length;
    
        queue[backIndex]= newEntry;
 }
    
}


public class main { 
    static objQueue<Object> queue=new  objQueue<Object> ;

    static pencil pen=new pencil(queue); //it gives error that The constructor pencil(objQueue<Object>) is undefined 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       queue.enqueue("pen")
       pen.pencil1();
}
```

this part is giving error static pencil pen=new pencil(queue); //it gives error that The constructor pencil(objQueue) is undefined
How can queue be written like ,static pencil pen=new pencil(queue),without giving error or any idea to write the code correctly ?

Comment: This question would really be way better with a good formatting

Comment: You've got a no-args constructor and one that takes an array.  Why do you expect it to know what to do when you pass in a single `objQueue` object?

Comment: This code is suspect.  Some of these statements would definitely not compile for syntax error.  It's also never a good idea to not follow the well established naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got confused because you're using the same name `queue` for the instance and its property.

The only constructor that exists for `pencil` has `T[]` as parameter which you would use like this.

```
static objQueue<Object> queue = new objQueue<Object> ;
// You'll need to have a getter added for queue
static pencil pen=new pencil(queue.getQueue()); // or queue.queue
```

BTW, you would also make your code more inline with standards if you started using camelcase for your class names `objQueue -> ObjQueue` and `pencil -> Pencil`